# Probability density function analysis question

Tags: probability

The distribution(normally distributed) of the amount of money that people withdraw from an ATM has an average of \$70 with a standard deviation  of \$10. If a group of 15 people withdraws money in a random day which is the probability that the total amount of money in a random day is more than \$1,000 but less than \$1,200?

Also, another question, if the bank wants the cashier to run out of enough money only 1% of the time, assuming that only 15 people withdraw money in any day, what amount of money does the ATM have to have so that it always have money in it?

My approach for the first question was:

$Z_{1} = \frac{1200 -70}{\frac{10}{\sqrt{15}}}, Z_{2} = \frac{1000 -70}{\frac{10}{\sqrt{15}}}$
and then CDF($Z_1$) - CDF($Z_2$)
Is my analysis correct?

For the second one I found the Z-Score of 1% using the inverse CDF. Then I did this,
$x = ZScore\left (  \frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{n}} \right ) + \mu =  -2.326\left (  \frac{10 }{\sqrt{15}} \right ) + 70 = 63.993$ so it is more than $63.993.

Am I right?

Comment: With the information given, the question is unanswerable.  As your work suggests, you have to assume the distribution of the sum is approximately Normal.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify that. It is normally distributed.